# iOS project won't build when certain pod files are included in files that are included in bridging header

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I found a bug that I'm kind of stumped by. Wondering if anyone else experienced this.

I have this [MBProgressHud](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) pod that I include in my `ViewController.h`. Presumably I'll use it in `ViewController.m` somewhere.

I also want to include `ViewController.h` in my bridging header so that I can write a Swift extension.

However, when I build and run, I get an error:

> 'MBProgressHUD.h' file not found

---

I've recreated the error in this project: https://github.com/zackshapiro/PodTest

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"
```

with

```
#import <MBProgressHUD/MBProgressHUD.h>
```

And all will be compiled. MBProgressHUD.h is a file from module MBProgressHUD therefore you can't include it with ""

Comment: Thanks for your help Andrew